# How to make SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan update the display on a non-UI thread?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm building an app that syntax highlights source code files. When a user clicks on the file, I want them to see the code as quickly as possible while I syntax-highlight code (CPU-intensive) in the background. Here's the code I wrote (it uses C# / Xamarin, but Java devs can translate this with some effort):

```
private void DisplayContent(IColorTheme theme)
{
    var text = new ColoredText(_content);
    _editor.SetText(text, TextView.BufferType.Editable);
    // The last param uses C# 7 syntax for tuples, don't worry about it
    Task.Factory.StartNew(HighlightContent, state: (text, theme));
}

private void HighlightContent(object state)
{
    var (text, theme) = ((ColoredText, IColorTheme))state;
    using (var colorer = TextColorer.Create(text, theme))
    {
        GetHighlighter().Highlight(_content, colorer);
    }
}
```

The important part is I'm first calling `SetText()` with a `ColoredText`, which is a custom type that just wraps a `SpannableStringBuilder`. Then, I'm calling `Task.Factory.StartNew`, which is one way in C# to run a callback (in this case, `HighlightContent`) on a new thread. Finally, `GetHighlighter().Highlight(...)` does most of the work and calls `SetSpan` on the text's underlying `SpannableStringBuilder` thousands of times.

When I run my app, I see the text, but it's all white. It's as if I omitted all of the syntax highlighting code completely and just wrote `_editor.SetText(...)`.  I strongly suspect this is because `SetSpan` is being run on a different thread. However, I *need* to run `SetSpan` on a different thread, since through profiling I have determined it is eating up a lot of CPU cycles. If I run it on the UI thread, my app will freeze for large files.

How do I make `SetSpan` update the display from a non-UI thread? (Don't suggest `runOnUiThread`, because again, I have to run this code on a non-UI thread.) Thanks.

Comment: if the problem was a different thread your app would crash with exception that UI cannot be updated from that thread OR it will be ignored. Looks likes it is ignored in your case. I also don't understand why you cannot use runOnUiThread only on that portion that updates the UI, everything else can be ran on different thread

Comment: @YuriS The portion that updates the UI is also CPU-intensive and freezing the UI.

Comment: You cannot update UI from non UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I spent a fair amount of time on this today and finally came up with a solution.

After asking this question, I debugged the app in Visual Studio and noticed that `setSpan` wasn't quite being ignored. Instead, it was hanging-- the statement after the first `setSpan` would never be run. After half an hour of head-scratching, I realized this would happen whenever `setSpan` got called after the rendering code.

My solution was hackish. I realized how `setSpan` updated the display was by checking for any `SpanWatcher`s currently attached to the `SpannableStringBuilder` and notifying them. I modified `ColoredText`'s [implementation of `setSpan`](https://github.com/jamesqo/Repository/blob/paginated-hl/java/repository/src/main/java/com/bluejay/repository/ColoredText.java#L137) so it would detect whether a `SpanWatcher` was being attached, and if so, wrap it in a new `SpanWatcher` that would run all the code on the UI thread.

```
@Override public void setSpan(Object o, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    if (o instanceof SpanWatcher) {
        o = new UiThreadSpanWatcher((SpanWatcher) o);
    }
    this.builder.setSpan(o, i, i1, i2);
}

public class UiThreadSpanWatcher implements SpanWatcher {
    private final SpanWatcher watcher;

    public UiThreadSpanWatcher(SpanWatcher watcher) {
        this.watcher = watcher;
    }

    @Override public void onSpanAdded(...) {
        Threading.postToUiThread(() -> {
            this.watcher.onSpanAdded(...);
        });
    }
}
```

Now all of the rendering code would be posted to the UI thread. However, this created a different problem: `setSpan` was being called lots of times, and I was posting thousands of callbacks to the UI thread, slaughtering performance. To mitigate this, I added the arguments into a list every time an overridden method was called, then added a `flush()` method which posted a single callback invoking the underlying watcher's method for each set of arguments.

```
private final List<Tuple4<...>> onSpanAddedArguments;

@Override public void onSpanAdded(...) {
    this.onSpanAddedArguments.add(new Tuple4<>(...));
}

public void flush() {
    Threading.postToUiThread(() -> {
        for (Tuple4<...> tuple : this.onSpanAddedArguments) {
            this.watcher.onSpanAdded(tuple.item1, tuple.item2, tuple.item3, tuple.item4);
        }
    });
}
```

There was a lot of boilerplate code involves, but in the end I finally got everything working. If the above didn't make the most sense to you, you can take a look at my project [here](https://github.com/jamesqo/Repository/blob/2f18c09b5bcd2ae7f5332213983367e87162a0fb/java/repository/src/main/java/com/bluejay/repository/UiThreadWatcher.java) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`postInvalidate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate()) or another method of its family after changing the contents of the `SpannableStringBuilder`. Only calling `setSpan()` does not tell the view it changed and needs to redraw.